# Black temporary alert box in iOS

Tags: ios, uikit

I need a black temporary transparent box that must show something like "Loading...." with a spinner it. We can see such a view in twitter when "Tweeting" an update - it says "Sending tweet..." kinda thing.

Is this an inbuilt behavior in UIKit. How do I get this box to show up on screen for a few seconds and disappear.

please help.

Comment: @Srikar, what should I do to improve it

Comment: for answers that helped you please mark them as "accepted answer". that's what the green tick mark is for. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [DSActivityView](https://github.com/joycodes/DSActivityView). All this is handled there. Instead of doing your own thing I suggest you use this.

For what you need this is how you need to go -

```
#import "DSActivityView.h"

[DSActivityView activityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Tweeting"]; //to show spinner with label

[DSActivityView removeView]; //once its done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)